# Mozilla Persona / BrowserID as auth method for a REST api

Tags: rest, authentication, browserid

I would like to use Persona as auth method for our website based on a whose functionalities are based on a REST API. In a traditional method we send the informations about user at each request - username and password - with the connection secured with SSL.

We would achieve the same, but using Mozilla Persona to allow people to the initial login instead, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is show a Web UI the first time (authenticating with Persona) and then exchange a secret token between the server and the client. You then include the token along with each request to the REST API.

That way you'd be using Persona for the initial authentication, then you'd be using a token-based system for authorization.